# Condition for collision

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

Assume we are given two particles of equal masses, with their velocity and position vectors, at some instant in time. Under what relationship of the velocity and position vectors will these masses collide?

Comment: your problem is 2D or 3D space ?

Comment: Draw the graph $x=f(t)$ for both masses on the same set of axes. Any point where the two curves intersect is a point of collision, since that implies they reach the same point in space at the same time. If your problem is multidimensional, repeat this for all spatial coordinates, and the point of collision only happens if for the same time, the curves of both masses for each coordinate ($x$, $y$ and $z$) interesect.

Comment: @Eli the problem is in 3D

Answer (score 1):

If the particles do not interact, then the condition is simply that their relative position vector $\vec{r} = \vec{r}_1 - \vec{r}_2$ and their relative velocity vector $\vec{v} = \vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_2$ are anti-parallel to each other (i.e., they point in exactly opposite directions).  This can be seen by moving to a reference frame where particle 2 is at rest at the origin.  If the two vectors $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ are exactly parallel to each other, this can be interpreted as though they collided at some point in the past and are now moving apart.

One easy way to check whether this is true is to take the cross product $\vec{r} \times \vec{v}$.  If this is zero then one of the two cases above must hold (the particles either will collide or have already collided.)  You would then need to check whether the particles are approaching or moving away.

If the particles *are* interacting (and they are point particles), it is still necessary that $\vec{r} \times \vec{v} = 0$ for a collision to occur.  However, depending on the details of the forces between them, this may not guarantee a collision.  For example, two positively charged point particles will never collide with each other because it would require an infinitely large amount of energy for them to be at zero separation.